# Possible to create AWS API Gateway generated SDK from scratch for Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an existing REST API in AWS API Gateway that I plan on accessing from an Android/Kotlin mobile app. Amplify handles Auth and Storage, but I don't want Amplify to handle the REST API, not that I could anyway (try yourself at own risk!).

API Gateway will generate an Android SDK, but since I used Proxy resources with the Any method, i.e. `/resource1/{proxy+}/Any()`, the generated Java code was very concise:

```
package com.my.clientsdk
import java.util.*

@Service(endpoint = "my-endpoint-url")
public interface MyClientSdk {
    ApiResponse execute(ApiRequest request);
}
```

I figured, why not just implement this in Kotlin along with the request/response POKOs? I'm running into problems initializing the client via instructions from the docs:

```
val factory = ApiClientFactory().apiKey("some-api-key")
val sdk = factory.build(MyClientSdk::class.java)
```

Setting a break point after this code, I get an error for variable `sdk`:

> Method threw
> 'com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException'
> exception. Cannot evaluate $Proxy6.toString()

The caller of this code is a UseCase invocation launched from a ViewModel coroutine, so it's not being done on the main thread (I've seen Java implementations using AsyncTask).

**How should I properly implement the API Gateway generated SDK for Android manually, in Kotlin?**

**Should I just use something like okhttp or ktor to send HTTP requests with the correct headers/body/etc.? Looks like I'd have to generate specific requests myself anyway. Would I have to enable CORS settings for this to work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just roll your own client interface.

After some debugging of vague AWS exceptions, I learned I needed to use internet/network permissions in the app. This would have been helpful info in the platform-specific docs.

Anyway, I am now at least getting error responses from my Lambda.

Comment: For what it's worth, the generated SDK clobbered all the query string params, proxy path, etc., so I'd recommend rolling your own.